# Ternary operation not working

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I'm trying to add ternary operators to my programming knowledge but they aren't working for me.

```
$_SESSION['c'] =  (isset($_GET['c'])) ? $_GET['c'];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)!

Comment: *Ternary* operators have **three** operands.

Comment: You have no `else` section in your ternary. So it's more like a "binary" operator right now.

Comment: i was in that page like in other 30 but still cant find the correct way..

Comment: there is no way to avoid the else( : ) part ?